# GetRouteUrl returning correct url in code behind but null in .aspx

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing, asp.net-4.5

I can correctly get at URL in a code-behind file, but the same statement returns nothing in an inline statement.

Here is part of my RegisterCustomRoutes method, which gets executed in Application_Start:

```cs
void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
     // Student list route
     routes.MapPageRoute(
          "StudentListRoute",
          "Course/{courseId}/Students",
          "~/path/to/page.aspx");

      // Course details route
      routes.MapPageRoute(
          "CourseDetailsRoute",
          "Course/{courseId}",
          "~/path/to/otherpage.aspx");

      ... some other route declarations
}
```

Then, in one of my .aspx pages, I have the following inline statement:

```html
<a href="<%# GetRouteURL("CourseDetailsRoute", new { courseId = 1}) %>">Some text</a>
```

I am expecting the generated URL to be:

```
/Course/1
```

Instead, nothing (either null or string.Empty) is returned. Again, I have confirmed that this statement correctly returns the desired URL in the code behind file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inline statement used the <%# ... %> tags, which are reserved for databinding purposes. Changed my inline statement to,

```html
<a href="<%: GetRouteUrl("RouteName", new { param = paramValue }) %>">Anchor text</a>
```

which resolved my issues.